# Unknown number of rows in UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

I want to create "very long" table with news, but I don't know how many news server exists. 1 cell = 1 news. When user will scroll his table, I will add cells with news dynamically.
I get news by bundles (first 5, second 5, ...).

What is the best way to set the number of rows?

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return ???
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to get the news from server:

If you are getting all the data (the whole news) in a single request (probably this is not what you want to achieve), you should return the number of the news array -somehow, you should have an array that contains the news model-:

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
      return news.count
}
```

If you are getting the news by bundles (let's say first ten and then second ten...), you will need to check if the tableview has reached the last cell for calling the server to get the next bundle of news, you can check by:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // if true, that means you reached the last row
        if indexPath.row == new.count - 1 {
            // request the server for getting the next bundle
            // ...

            // append responsed data to news array
            // ...

            // call tableView.reloadData()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: glad to help, shoot a comment if you need some help. And don't forget to accept it if it works for you :)

Comment: tableView.reloadData() called many times, so it's not working

Comment: when tableView.reloadData() get called, the number of the rows should be increased

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to a web service connection or ssh for learn how many news you have and you can fetch news count and use.

```
var fetchedNewsCount: Int?


func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return self.fetchedNewCount
}
```